# Should I do a different SQL table for user privacy settings or just keep it at the users table?

Tags: mysql, efficiency

So I am developing a Web Application and I have some concerns about the database. I use a lot of boolean settings at the user table with the form privacy_allow_1, privacy_allow_that, privacy_allow_this etc etc.

As they keep stacking would it be just better to use a different table just for the privacy settings and link it to the users?

What are the prons and cons between the two options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another table with a schema similar to

```
userid
PrivacyTypeId
allowed
```

and

```
PrivacyTypeId
PrivacyType
```

This structure will allow you to add\remove\deactivate permissions without any DDL changes